How to get WPF to reinspect the CanExecute of a Button when the underlying data changes
I have a simple MVVM app to search for SwiftMessages, display a list of them, and then let the user click on a button to open a secondary view to display one. I want the Open button to stay disabled until the user has searched for and selected a message. I'm doing this with two Views, two ViewModels:



View
ViewModel




SwiftSearchWindow
SwiftSearchViewModel


SwiftMessageWindow
SwiftMessageViewModel



In the SwiftSearchWindow XAML I have a DataGrid and an open Button:
            <DataGrid Name="gridMessages" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SwiftMessages}" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMessage}" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message Type" Binding="{Binding MessageType}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
...
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Own Bic" Binding="{Binding OwnBic}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
...
            <Button Name="btnOpen" 
                Command="{Binding OpenMessageCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedMessage}">
                Open
            </Button>

In SwiftMessagesViewModel, I have:
    public class SwiftSearchViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
...
        private ICommand _openMessageCommand;
...
        public SwiftSearchViewModel()
        {
            // ICommands
            _openMessageCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenMessage, (param) => OpenMessageCanExecute(param));
        }
...
        public MVVM6.Models.Messages SwiftMessages
        {
            get
            {
                return _messages;
            }
        }

        private Message _selectedMessage = null;
        public Message SelectedMessage
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedMessage; 
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedMessage));
            }
        }
...
        public ICommand OpenMessageCommand => _openMessageCommand;
        private bool OpenMessageCanExecute(object param)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"SwiftSearchViewMode.OpenMessageCanExecute {(_selectedMessage != null)}");
            return (_selectedMessage != null);
        }

        private void OpenMessage(object param)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SwiftSearchViewModel.OpenMessage " + param?.GetType().Name);

        }
    }

When the user selects a message, the SelectedItem property gets set correctly, but nothing calls OpenMessageCanExecute doesn't get called by the WPF magic glue and my Open button stays disabled.
How do I persuade WPF to reinspect the RelayCommand and hence enable the Open button?

Hello again, if you inspect your RelayCommand you will notice an event there called CanExecuteChanged MSDN call that when you need to refresh your command

Hello! That's exactly the type of thing I was looking for. Thank you.

What is RelayCommand? MVVM Light?

Every MVVM library will have their own implementation of ICommand - RelayCommand is a common name, e.g. CommunityToolkit.Mvvm - https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. Prism calls their variation DelegateCommand
